# SQL Server 2008 Management Console: Automatically write results to a script and execute it

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

I would like to write a script which produces various statements out of a database.

Something like :

```
select 'DROP TABLE ['+ name + ']' from sys.objects where type = 'T' ;
```

I would like to automatically collect all output of such statements in a new file, and then I would like to execute this file. Is this possible ?

**Important:** The output should of course be without headers and without any other error/success, messages and so on.

In the optimal case, all necessary options for this should be set in the script itself, other than setting them in the user interface.

Comment: You should use `sys.tables` instead - then you don't need any `type = ...` specifier. BTW: `type = 'T'` is wrong - it should be `type = 'U'` (`U` as in `user table`) - but as I mentioned - if you use `select name from sys.tables`, then you don't need to remember those thorny details....

Comment: What's wrong with executing dynamic script and then saving it to file? This can be simply implemented by collecting everything to variable, printing that variable to SSMS Messages-window, using exec to execute that and finally saving output script from messages.

Comment: Hello, can you pleae be so kind and give an example? 
Probably it is 'simply' to you, but not for me :-). 

To clarify what I do now: In the menu, I select "Query results to file." Then I start the script, and I need to enter a filename. After the script is complete, I open the file, MANUALLY remove lines like "-----" and "17 lines", and then I execute the new script. 

I would like to automate this further, i.e. such that no entering of a filename, no manual cleanup is necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you create you dynamic script, something like...

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)  
SELECT @sql = 
     COALESCE(@sql + CHAR(13), '') + 
     'DROP TABLE ['+ name + ']' 
FROM sys.objects 
WHERE [type] = 'T'
```

Execute that...

```
EXEC(@sql)
```

Then print that out to Messages-window...

```
PRINT @sql
```

And finally go to Messages-window, right-click it, select "Save results as...", Save as type > all files, and write your file name like myfile.sql

**EDIT**

I would never, EVER execute something like this automatically and without transaction. I'd rather save a script from Messages-window, open it, review it and then execute.

Comment: Thank you a lot, now understand this better. Actually, the "EXEC" part executes the generated DROP statement, so this is really dangerous. 

I'd prefer to print the statements to a file first, and then execute this file.

BUT, is it possible for the PRINT command to set the filename somehere in the script, instead of saving the file manually ?

Comment: As far as I know, it isn't possible. Maybe using some SQLCMD mode hack, but I'm not very fond of it. You may try this though: [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_server_appendix_z/archive/2013/02/23/sql-server-management-studio-sqlcmd-meets-the-richter-scale.aspx](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_server_appendix_z/archive/2013/02/23/sql-server-management-studio-sqlcmd-meets-the-richter-scale.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Are you wanting something like this?

**If you only want to print the script use `osql` and a script something like this**

```
DECLARE @schema VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @table VARCHAR(255)

DECLARE PrintOutputCursor CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT [TABLE_SCHEMA], [TABLE_NAME]
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
OPEN PrintOutputCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM PrintOutputCursor INTO @schema, @table
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    PRINT 'DROP TABLE ['+ @schema + '].[' + @table + '];'
    FETCH NEXT FROM PrintOutputCursor INTO @schema, @table
END
CLOSE PrintOutputCursor
DEALLOCATE PrintOutputCursor
```

**If you want to execute the script using `osql` use this script (NOT RECOMMENDED)**

```
DECLARE @schema VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @table VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @exec VARCHAR(4000)

DECLARE PrintOutputCursor CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT [TABLE_SCHEMA], [TABLE_NAME]
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
OPEN PrintOutputCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM PrintOutputCursor INTO @schema, @table
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    SET @exec = 'DROP TABLE ['+ @schema + '].[' + @table + '];'
    -- Uncomment the following to execute the dynamic statement
    -- EXEC (@exec)
    FETCH NEXT FROM PrintOutputCursor INTO @schema, @table
END
CLOSE PrintOutputCursor
DEALLOCATE PrintOutputCursor
```

Comment: Hm looks quite good, but is it possible to enter a filename there? Also, is it possible to execute the script, right after it has been written ?